# 2 columns with DIV .... max size for the second

Tags: html, css

I have this code :

```
<div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:Lime;">
    <div style="float:left;width:150px; background-color:Red;">
        AAAA
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;background-color:Fuchsia;margin-left:10px;">
        BBBB
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

The first column has fix size, I'd like the second have the rest of the with available in the container div.

Any idea ?

Update1:
My code give this : http://tinypic.com/r/103x65e/6
I'd like the magenta arrive to the arrow

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can change the left margin of the second column to 150px+10px=160px and remove the float: left. Additionally you can add the clearfix class as stated by Staicu, which removes the need for a BR element with "clear:both". If you like to have both columns have the same height you can use the Faux Column trick as stated by Staicu. If things break in Internet Explorer you can fix it with the info found on [positioniseverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/guillotine.html)

```
<div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:Lime;" class="clearfix">
    <div style="float:left; width:150px; background-color:red;">
        AAAA
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:fuchsia; margin-left:160px;">
        BBBB
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gr8... i was searching for the same... it worked in IE 6, 7, 8, Fireforx 2+ and even chrome... :) thnx alot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just curious: WHY?

1. you can use [clearfix](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) fix;
2. you can use [faux column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) trick;

Comment: Why, because I have a title in the second column, a decoration line under, and I want this line on the complete with. Like this http://tinypic.com/r/fy3mgi/6

Comment: could you tell me more about solution 1 ?

Comment: Oh, you mean the width? Then you just need to specify width for the first column and `margin-left` equal to first column width :)

Clearfix is used to clear floats in a better (and easy) way.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `display: table[-row|-cell]` property. It gives use table-like bahaviour.